# How to convert Json table (array of arrays) data to a collection of c# objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a table like (array of arrays) object in json format that I would like to convert to a collection of c# objects.

```
{
    "Columns": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "column name 1",
            "other stuff": "blah blah"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "column name 2",
            "other stuff": "blah blah"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "column name 3",
            "other stuff": "blah blah"
        }
    ],
    "Data": [
         [
             "blah bla",
             "bloop",
             1
         ],
        [
            "t",
            "another random value",
            5
        ],
        [
            "foo",
            "bar",
            5
        ],
        [
            "something valuable",
            "value2",
            5
        ]
    ]
}
```

I would like to serialize that into a collection of objects or data table similar to the following:

```
public class Row
{
     public string ColumnName1 {get;set;}
     public string ColumnName2 {get;set;}
     public int ColumnName3 {get;set;}
}

var jsonString = "same as above just properly escaped"; 
list<Row> rows = Deserialize(jsonString);
```

The column mappings would be consistent based on the order of the values.

**Edit:**

I would love to have the data in a more c# friendly way similar to this example:

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "column name 1": "blah bla"
        },
        {
            "column name 1": "T"
        },
        {
            "column name 1": "blahbla"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I don't have control over that so...

Comment: Does your Data object doesn't have keys???

Comment: The "Data" object in the json is an array of arrays so no it doesn't have keys. Conceptually the keys are stored in the columns array, and their known/static. T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API to parse the JSON data into the format that you want:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
List<Row> rows = jo["Data"]
    .Children<JArray>()
    .Select(ja => new Row
    {
        ColumnName1 = (string)ja[0],
        ColumnName2 = (string)ja[1],
        ColumnName3 = (int)ja[2]
    })
    .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bA9vSH

Comment: I was really hoping this was common enough I was just missing some kind of attribute or something but this is easy/clean enough. Thanks!